# SQL Server INNER JOIN multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, join

I have the following statement where selecting 2 tables from a different server and doing inner join but getting multi-part identifier could not be bound.

```
select *
from [SQ05].[mov].[dbo].[item_movement] inner join [SQ05].[mov].[dbo].[item_master]
on [SQ05].[mov].[dbo].[item_movement].[item_id] = [SQ05].[mov].[dbo].[item_master].[item_id]


Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "SQ05.mov.dbo.item_movement.item_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "SQ05.mov.dbo.item_master.item_id" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple `ALIAS`

```
select *
from [SQ05].[mov].[dbo].[item_movement] AS imo inner join [SQ05].[mov].[dbo].[item_master] 
AS ima
on imo.[item_id] =  ima.[item_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

removing db ids in the ON fixed the issue

```
select *
from [SQ05].[mov].[dbo].[item_movement] inner join [SQ05].[mov].[dbo].[item_master]
on [item_movement].[item_id] = [item_master].[item_id]
```